# Access a given cell of a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

It may seem easy but I cannot find the way: `dt.Rows[r].Cells[c]` does not work for DataTable.

This is what I have tried. I do not have other ideas.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What happens?

Comment: Now I see I must write:
dt.Rows[r][c]

Comment: Try `dt.Rows[r][c]` or `dt.Rows[r].ItemArray[c]` instead.

Comment: Seems that you already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

`dt.Rows[r]` should return a [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.7.1) assuming `r` is an `int` value between `0` and `dt.Rows.Count-1` inclusive.

To get a specific cell value from a `DataRow` you use one of it's indexers, so you don't need the `.Cells` - you can just do `dt.Rows[r][c]` where `c` is either an `int`, a `string` or a `DataColumn`